# htacess mod_rewrite not working (But it works on same server in other directory)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have this hatcess mod rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ find.php?q=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/([0-9])$ find.php?q=$1&psl=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)-links$ find.php?q=$1&hostas=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ details.php?id=$3 [NC]
```

The problem is it works perfectly on one of my domains, and it gives 404 error on other domain hosted on same server (hostgator) but in other directory. The needed files find.php and detals.php do exist in both directories. any suggestions why it doesnt work?

Comment: I've tried using / before $, also without [NC].. nothing helped

Comment: What are you trying to match with this `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$...`, because it doesn't seem to be matching anything? Please include in your question complete incoming URL samples to understand what the rules are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it gives 404 error on other domain hosted on same server but in other directory

You must define this folder as the base for `mod-rewrite` in your other folder :

```
(...)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourfolder/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com
(...)
```